# In what direction does skin effect take place?

Tags: electromagnetism, transmission-line, high-frequency, coaxial, skin-effect

I'm working with some problems with coaxial cylinders and the currents driven in those when considering high frequencies. In such cases, the skin depth has to be taken into consideration.

One thing I seem to struggle is to decide in what "direction" so to speak, that the skin depth is to be considered. For instance, if we put a voltage between the inner and outer radius of a coaxial cylinder, the skin depth has to be taken into consideration along the height of the cylinder. However, if the voltage is between the bottom and top part of the coaxial cylinder, the skin depth has to be taken into consideration along the radial direction of the cylinder.

Is there some easy way to think / determine in which direction the skin depth has to be taken into consideration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *For instance, if we put a voltage between the inner and outer radius
> of a coaxial cylinder, the skin depth has to be taken into
> consideration along the height of the cylinder. However, if the
> voltage is between the bottom and top part of the coaxial cylinder,
> the skin depth has to be taken into consideration along the radial
> direction of the cylinder.*

Think about the resulting current flow.

- if you apply a voltage to both ends of the shield or, both ends of the inner conductor, current flow will be **along the axial length** of the coax
- If voltage is applied between the inner conductor and the outer shield, then current flow will still be **along the axial length** of the coax (providing there is a load terminating the coax). The only difference here is that there will be a current flowing in the inner conductor of opposite polarity to the current flowing in the shield conductor.

So, the appearance of skin effect will be the same in both scenarios.

However, if you are considering an unterminated coax of short length (i.e. not a transmission line), then any current that flows between inner conductor and outer shield will be purely capacitive in nature and, due to the large surface area involved, skin effect will not be significant.